# Add a Future<String> to a notifier provider

Tags: flutter, dart

Now that I am getting the document id back from the saveNewClient function how do I use the variable to add the id to the client provider? Here is the code:

```
Future<String?> clientId =
          firestoreService.saveNewClient(toMap(newClient));
      ref.read(clientNotifierProvider.notifier).updateClientId(clientId); <<<< PROBLEM HERE
```

Here is the saveNewClient function:

```
  Future<String?> saveNewClient(client) async {
    // Get the document ID of the new document so it can be
    // added to the new transaction document.
    try {
      /// You can generate a document id before the create operate
      String id = _db.collection("client").doc().id;

      /// pass the generated id to the doc reference and set it
      /// .toMap() -> Assuming your client isn't of type map
      await _db.collection('client').doc(id).set(client.toMap());

      /// upon success return the id
      return id;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);

      /// or return null if the operation failed
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Since clientId is a future I need to wait for it to be populated. How do I do this? Thanks